# Is there a stack overflow danger with strtok here?

Tags: c, security, stack-overflow

Below is some code which I ran through a static analyzer. It came back saying there is a stack overflow vulnerability in the function that uses `strtok` below, as described here:

https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/121.html

If you trace the execution, the variables used by strtok ultimately derive their data from the `user_input` variable in `somefunction` coming in from the wild. But I figured I prevented problems by first checking the length of user_input as well as by explicitly using `strncpy` with a bound any time I copied pieces of user_input.

```
somefunction(user_input) {

   if (strlen(user_input) != 23) {
        if (user_input != NULL)
            free(user_input);
        exit(1);
    }

    Mystruct* mystruct = malloc(sizeof(Mystruct));

    mystruct->foo = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    memset(mystruct->foo, '\0', 3);
    strncpy(mystruct->foo,&(user_input[0]),2);

    mystruct->bar = malloc(19 * sizeof(char));
    memset(mystruct->bar, '\0', 19);

    /* Remove spaces from user's input. strtok is not guaranteed to
     * not modify the source string so we copy it first.
     */
    char *input = malloc(22 * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(input,&(user_input[2]),21);
    remove_spaces(input,mystruct->bar);
}

void remove_spaces(char *input, char *output) {
    const char space[2] = " ";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(input, space);

    while( token != NULL ) {
        // the error is indicated on this line
        strncat(output, token, strlen(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, space);
    }
}
```

I presumed that I didn't have to malloc `token` per this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641595/9727704), and elsewhere. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Stack overflow is not likely without any recursion or allocation of a VLA. I don't see any way that `remove_spaces()` could cause a stack overflow. Are you sure that's what the analyzer said?

Comment: BTW, `strtok()` is *required* to modify the source string.

Comment: You should check that `user_input` is not `NULL` before checking its length.

Comment: [strncpy manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy): "*Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated*". It's common to think that `strncpy` is entirely safe. It isn't if used incorrectly. Not saying that's definetely the issue here but it looks possible to me. It's possible for `input` to not be NUL terminated. Use `calloc` or `input[21]='\0'`

Comment: Yeah, thats what it said. I wanted to check before I dismiss it as an FP.

Comment: You're not copying the null terminator in your `strncpy()`.

Comment: The string length is 23, and you're copying the 21 characters starting from index 2. That doesn't include the null terminator.

Comment: I don't see anything that would even remotely suggest the possibility of stack overflow. It seems like a bug in the analyzer, unless you're misreading it. Can you post the exact text of the report?

Comment: It just says, "the call to strncat contains a buffer overflow"

Comment: "buffer overflow" is not the same as "stack overflow". The code calls `strncat` in a loop, appending to an output buffer of unspecified size. So the analyzer is right to warn you that the code can potentially overrun the buffer. BTW, `strncat(output, token, strlen(token))` is silly. It's exactly the same as `strcat(output, token)`. To use `strncat` effectively, the length parameter must be the number of bytes available in the output buffer.

Comment: OK, noted. However outbut buffer size is not unspecified, it is set to 19 bytes. FWIW elsewhere in the tool it is called a "Stack-based Buffer Overflow" as with the Mitre CWE page linked above.

Comment: The correct way to solve the problem is to write an in-place algorithm, e.g. `int k=0; for (int i=0; buffer[i]; i++) { if (buffer[i] != ' ') buffer[k++] = buffer[i]; } buffer[k] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy` does not increase the safety of your code; indeed, it may well make the code *less* safe by introducing the possibility of an unterminated output string. But the issue being flagged by the static analyser involves neither with `strncpy` nor `strtok`; it's with `strncat`.

Although they are frequently touted as increasing code safety, that was never the purpose of `strncpy`, `strncat` nor `strncmp`. The `strn*` alternatives to `str*` functions are intended for use in a context in which string data is not null-terminated. Such a context exists, although it is rare in student code: fixed-length string fields in fixed-size database records. If a field in a database record always contains 20 characters (`CHAR(20)` in SQL terms), there's no need to force a trailing 0-byte, which could have been used to allow 21-character names (or whatever the field is). It's a waste of space, and the only reason that those unnecessary bytes might be examined by the database code is to check database integrity. (Not that the extra byte really helps maintain integrity, either. But it must be checked for correctness.)

If you were writing code which used or created fixed-length unterminated string fields, you would certainly need a set of string functions which accept a length argument. But the string library already had those functions: `memcpy` and `memcmp`. The `strn` versions were added to ease the interface when both null-terminated and fixed-length strings are being used in the same application; for example, if a null-terminated string is read from user input and needs to be copied into a fixed-length database field. In that context, the interface of `strncpy` makes sense: the database field must be completed cleared of old data, but the input string might be too short to guarantee that. So you can't use `strcpy` even if you check that it won't overflow (because it doesn't necessarily erase old data) and you can't use `memcpy` (because the bytes following the end of the input string are indeterminated). Hence an interface like `strncpy`, which guarantees that the destination will be filled but doesn't guarantee that it will be null-terminated.

`strncmp` and `strnlen` do have some applications which don't necessarily have to do with fixed-length string records, but they are not safety-related either. `strncmp` is handy if you want to know whether a given string is a prefix of another string (although a `startswith` function would have more directly addressed this use case) and `strnlen` lets you answer the question "Are there at least four characters in this string?" without having to worry about how many cycles would be wasted if the string continued for another four million characters. But that doesn't justify using them in other, more normal, contexts.

OK, that was a bit of a detour. Let's get back to `strncat`, whose prototype is

```c
    char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

where `n` is the maximum number of characters to copy. As the man page notes, *you* (and not the standard library) are responsible for ensuring that the destination has `n+1` bytes available for the copy. The library function cannot take responsibility, because it cannot know how much space is available, and it hasn't asked you to specify that.

In my opinion, that makes `strncat` completely useless. In order to know how much space is available in the destination, you need to know where the concatenation's copy will start. But if you knew that, why on earth would you ask the standard library to scan over the destination looking for the concatenation point? In any case, you are not verifying how much space is available; you simply call:

```c
strncat(output, token, strlen(token));
```

That does *exactly the same thing* as `strcat(output, token)` except that it scans `token` twice (once to count the bytes and a second time to copy them) and during the copy it does a redundant check to ensure that the count has not been exceeded while copying.

A "safe" version of `strncat` would require you to specify the length of the *destination*, but since there is no such function in the standard C library and also no consensus as to what the prototype for such a function would be, you need to guarantee safety yourself by tracking the amount of space used in `output` by each concatenation. As an extra benefit, if you do that, you can then make the computational complexity of a sequence of concatenations  linear in the number of bytes copied, which one might intuitively expect, as opposed to quadratic, as implemented by `strcat` and `strncat`.

So a safe and efficient procedure might look like this:

```c
void remove_spaces(char *output, size_t outmax,
                   char *input) {
    if (outmax = 0) return;
    char *token = strtok(input, " ");
    char *outlimit = output + outmax;
    while( token ) {
        size_t tokelen = strlen(token);
        if (tokelen >= outlimit - output)
            tokelen = outlimit - output - 1;
        memcpy(output, token, tokelen);
        output += tokelen;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    *output = 0;
}
```

The CWE warning does not mention `strtok` at all, so the question in the title itself is a red herring. `strtok` is one of the few parts of your code which is not problematic, although (as you note) it does force an otherwise unnecessary copy of the input string, in case that string is in read-only memory. (As noted above, `strncpy` does not guarantee that the copy is null-terminated, so it is not safe here. `strdup`, which needs to be paired with `free`, is the safest way to copy a string. Fortunately, it will still be part of the C standard instead of just being available almost everywhere.)

That might be a good enough reason to avoid `strtok`. If so, it's easy to get rid of:

```c
void remove_spaces(char *output, size_t outmax,
                   /* This version doesn't modify input */
                   const char *input) {
    if (outmax = 0) return;    
    char *token = strtok(input, " ");
    char *outlimit = output + outmax;
    while ( *(input += strspn(input, " ")) ) {
        size_t cpylen = (tokelen < outlimit - outptr)
                           ? tokelen 
                           : outlimit - outptr - 1;
        memcpy(output, input, cpylen);
        output += cpylen;
        input += tokelen;
    }
    *output = 0;
}
```

A better interface would manage to indicate whether the output was truncated, and perhaps give an indication of how many bytes were necessary to accommodate the operation. See `snprintf` for an example.